# BitmapFactory.decodeStream not working for Android 8?

Tags: android, bitmap

I use this code to get image as bitmap from internal storage. This code not working for Android 8. I gives java.io.FileNotFoundException: (No such file or directory) error.

```
 private void loadImageFromStorage(String id)
    {
        ContextWrapper cw = new ContextWrapper(getApplicationContext());
        File directory = cw.getDir("imageDir", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        try {
            File f=new File(directory, id + ".jpg");
            Bitmap b = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(new FileInputStream(f));

        }
        catch (FileNotFoundException e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
```

How Can ı solve this problem? Its work for other Android versions.

Comment: I would start by getting rid of the `ContextWrapper`, as you do not need it. If that does not help, you may want to edit your question to provide the complete stack trace of your crash.

Comment: Use f.exists() before trying to create a bitmap.